# Adding a second item to a list seems to override the first element I added

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, indexing, webdriver

So I'm trying to add 2 Item objects into a list by looping through it but somehow the 2nd item overrides the first one. Sorry it's been a while since I coded so I'm having a hard time figuring out what I did wrong as I expect that the name for these items are different. :D

```
public static List<Item> buyList = new ArrayList<Item>();
int qty=2;

public static void buyItems(int qty)
{
    for(int i=1; i<=qty; i++)
    {
        Item thisItem = new Item();
        thisItem.setName(driver.findElement("//xpathOfName["+i+"]").getText()));
        thisItem.setPrice(driver.findElement("//xpathOfPrice["+i+"]").getText()));

//      System.out.println("this item is >>>>>>>>" +thisItem.getName());

        buyList.add(thisItem);

//      System.out.println("item at 0 is >>>>>>>>" +buyList.get(0).getName());
    }
}
```

Before adding "thisItem" into the buyList, it prints the correct name. But the moment I print it outside the loop, it prints the 2nd item twice (the ones I commented out). I also tried by directly adding a new item with name and price as parameters but it still seems to overwrite the previously added item into the list.

I tried to simplify the html code below:

```
<ul>
   <li id="item-1">
      <div>
         <h4>First Item</h4>
      </div>
   </li>
   <li id="item-2">
      <div>
         <h4>Second Item</h4>
      </div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Is it possible `xpathOfName["i"]` isn't actually finding your first element? There is nothing wrong with your Java Code. You can debug this with a normal list of objects.  To be more clear, paste your HTML codes too.

Also you are not printing outside the loop, you are printing outside method too. Since this is a static list, shouldn't matter. Just pointing out clarifications for future readers.

Comment: Debug your code to see all the values.

Comment: Pasted simplified HTML code. As you can see, the reason why I had to create the xpath like that (embedding the index into the xpath string) is because the HTML contains a dynamic variable name (item-1, item-2, item-3....). I needed to do that so I can get a specified number of those items. I fixed the print outside of the method. It is supposed to be inside. Had something to do with editing the code here to remove unnecessary lines.

Answer (score 1):

As you have induced the loop and you want to access the element through an *index*, you need to replace the following lines:

```
thisItem.setName(driver.findElement("//xpathOfName["+i+"]").getText()));
thisItem.setPrice(driver.findElement("//xpathOfPrice["+i+"]").getText()));
```

With:

```
thisItem.setName(driver.findElements("//xpathOfName").get(i).getText()));
thisItem.setPrice(driver.findElements("//xpathOfPrice").get(i).getText()));
```

Comment: Or start with i = 0;

Comment: @pburgr Right !!! OP seems to be controlling the value of `i` dynamically, so kept a provision so he can choose the desired value.

Comment: Thanks! I will try this out later. Have to study for an upcoming exam first.

Comment: So I revisited the code today and found that the suggested solution is not applicable. Reason is that I constructed the xpath string that way because the html generates a dynamic naming for the items (e.g. item1, item2, item3....).